# Concat JavaScripts like Rails Assets Pipeline in Grunt

Tags: gruntjs

I'd like to define concat order in application.js like Rails.

ex)

```
// application.js
//= require jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
//= require bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Is there plugin that this can solve? I don't like write order in Gruntfile.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for grunt-rigger - https://github.com/DamonOehlman/grunt-rigger

Comment: That doesn't look like it is still developed.

Comment: we're using it in product daily. is there a particular feature you need that you don't see?